# Do I Need an FCS (Passenger Locator Form) if Entering Spain by Road?

Tags: covid-19, driving, buses, spain

Thanks for helping out. I'm entering Spain via a flight to France and then coach transfer to Santander in Cantabria. I have all in order to arrive in France but would like to understand:

- If I need an FCS (Formulario de Control Sanitario / Passenger Locator Form) to enter Spain by road
- If so, how to obtain this for entering via road, [the website](https://www.spth.gob.es/) only has options for arriving by Air or Sea

Note that everyone in my group is originating from the UK, is fully vaccinated and has the [NHS QR code that is accepted in Spain](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/MANCHESTER/es/VivirEnReinoUnido/Documents/Preguntas%20frecuentes%20ENG%2002.07.2021.pdf) to demonstrate this when required.

So far I've looked at the [relevant French travel guidance](https://es.ambafrance.org/Covid-19-lo-que-hay-que-saber-antes-de-viajar-a-Francia) which makes no mention of the FCS, Looked at the [Spanish guidance](https://www.mscbs.gob.es/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spth.htm) which says the form is necessary but then links back to the air / sea page linked above and tried [generally googling](https://www.spth.gob.es/) for an answer but arriving by road appears to be a grey area.

I'm keen to avoid problems on arrival and one option would be to fill out the FCS with details of the flight into France but I'm unsure if this would be accepted by the online form. Does anybody have recent experience of how to fill in an FCS in Spain if arriving by road or know if this is required?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do not need it. From [the consular office at Lyon](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LYON/es/Consulado/Paginas/Articulos/06-04-20-CONEXI%C3%93N-LYON-ESPA%C3%91A.aspx)

> 1.B. Entradas por vía terrestre

> Todas las personas de 12 años o más, procedentes de países o zonas de riesgo que lleguen a España por vía terrestre deberán disponer de alguna de las certificaciones que arriba se recogen (de vacunación o prueba diagnóstica o recuperación). Quedan exceptuados de este requisito:

That basically says that everybody over 12 crossing into Spain through land must have a valid CCD (minus a few exception for transportist, people living near the border and people who must cross the border for work regularly).

Also, point 2 is:

> 2. Formulario de control sanitario (entradas por vía aérea o marítima)​

which means "Sanitary Control Form (entry by air or sea)" which makes it rather clear that it does not appy to land travel.

A bit of a worrying point is that it tells that people

> tiene que llevar consigo un certificado digital COVID emitido por un estado miembro de la Unión Europea (UE)*, que certifique alguno de los siguientes requisitos sanitarios:

must carry a COVID Digital Certificate issued by a member of the EU, which the UK isn't, but it looks more like an oversight than a refusal to accept UK's certificates.